# Tkinter command issue in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I can't recognize the difference between:

```
b = tkinter.button(...,command=FuncName())
```

and

```
b = tkinter.button(...,command=FuncName)
```

it seems that it only works without the brackets, why? Can somebody tell me the mechanism?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write:

```
b = tkinter.button(...,command=FuncName())
```

it means, "call FuncName() right now and it will return a function to call later when the button is pressed."  When you write:

```
b = tkinter.button(...,command=FuncName)
```

it means, "call FuncName() later, when the button is pressed."

The parenthesis invoke the function, without them, we're just passing the function around like any other data type.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
b = tkinter.button(...,command=FuncName())
```

... is exactly the same as this code:

```
result = FuncName()
b = tkinter.button(...,command=result)
```

Tkinter needs a *reference* to a function. When you add `()`, you are calling the function and giving tkinter the *result* of the function.

The first version will actually work fine if `FuncName()` returns a function. That's rarely how people use the `command` attribute).